# Sporadic keyless entry (2013 Altima)

Tags: toyota, nissan, keyless-entry

A few months ago, the keyless entry on my Altima became sporadic in reliability, and sometimes once I got in, the screen would give a "Key ID incorrect" error. I can get the fob to work if I hold it towards the front of the car, but not if I'm just next to the door handle. I know it's not the battery, because last time I got a notification on the screen of low fob battery, and changed it earlier this year.

A few months ago, my roommate also bought a 2004 Toyota Sequoia. Now call me crazy, but it seems whenever I'm not around the Sequoia, keyless entry works fine, while freaking out more when the two cars are next to each other. Is it plausible that the Toyota is causing interference with my fob somehow, and if so, how could this be mitigated?

In case it matters (doubtful), the Sequoia has an aftermarket DVD player, radio, and backup cam, but no remote unlock capability. The Nissan is a 2013 S model with no aftermarket anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems obvious you are having some frequency interference.

According to the **Auto Service Professional** website's article on *[Interference for keyless entry](http://www.autoserviceprofessional.com/article/94845/interference-for-keyless-entry)*, "Some aftermarket devices can cause frequency interference".

This would explain why you only have the issue when the other vehicle (with aftermarket accessories) is park near yours. As the article states, any accessory, like a USB charger has the potential to cause issues if it is left energized all the time.

To reduce the chance of this happening, find the accessory causing interference and unplug/remove it. In the case of it being property of someone else, try to park farther away.

Comment: Good to know, I'll look more into this